# WinCE: unable to insert data into sdf database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some problem in setting the path of my SDF db.

My original connection

```
<add name="Model1Container" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Then I tried to use ConfigurationManager to get the db connection string but it produces an error (metadata not support)

After that, instead of using connection string I have tried several other methods such as:

```
string StartupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        string datalogicFilePath = Path.Combine(StartupPath, "Database1.sdf");
        string connectionString = string.Format("DataSource={0}", datalogicFilePath);
```

This one will throw URI format exception

```
@"Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Database1.sdf"
```

This one able to return 1 for ExecuteNonQuery, but I can't see any changes on the db it self.

Then I realized that it might be the Copy to Output directory properties. I tried "do not copy" and it yielded error message where bin\database1.sdf not found. I have set it back to "Copy if newer".

But when I was using full path to the database C:.....................\Project\database1.sdf, it able to update the db. Is there any possible way of doing it rather than providing a full path?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and finally solved it,
Actually it saves the data but not in the .sdf it shows in server explorer (which is in root folder of application usually) but in the .sdf in debug folder
also when u publish the application it publishes with the the root one .sdf which inserts the data normally.
hope i haven't confuse you and it helped you.
-Masology

Answer (score 0):

try to use your local path
Data Source=C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ABC\ABC\Database1.sdf;Password=qwer!234;Persist Security Info=True"